# Not getting C++ Struct using JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I have googled for a long time, and nothing helps.

EDIT: This is the code after implementing technomage's advice.

Example struct C++ code:

```
typedef struct _SOMESTRUCT{
    const char* String1;
    const char* String2;
} SOMESTRUCT, *LPSOMESTRUCT;
```

Example C++ function that "fills up" the struct with data:

```
int GetSomeStruct(_SOMESTRUCT somes);
```

Translation of struct to java:

```
public class SomeStruct extends Structure{
    public String String1;
    public String String2;
    public class ByValue extends SomeStruct implements Structure.ByValue{}
    public SomeStruct(Pointer p){ //constructors of struct
        super(p);
        read();
    }
    public SomeStruct(){
         super();
         read();
    }
}
```

Translation of function to java method:

```
int GetSomeStruct(SomeStruct.ByValue structref);
```

How I execute the code from main Java app:

```
EnclosingClass.SomeStruct sstruct = enclosingInstance.new SomeStruct();
EnclosingClass.SomeStruc.ByValue sstructval = sstruct.new ByValue();
enclosingInstanceofClasswithTranslatedCfunctions.GetSomeStruct(sstructref);
```

Assumptions:

- I have correctly executed Native.loadLibrary before attempting to use the function. (simpler functions that return ints work fine as does a callback function for receiving event notifications)
- The java translations are both in separate files (as in the c code) nested in public classes that extend JNA library.
- The int that is returned by GetSomeStruct is zero if everything executes well on the c side. I keep getting zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your native declaration passes a struct by value.  The following declarations are equivalent:

```
int GetSomeStruct(struct _SOMESTRUCT somes);
int GetSomeStruct(SOMESTRUCT somes);
```

You need to define your Java mapping to explicitly accept an argument which implements the `Structure.ByValue` interface.  JNA assumes `struct*` by default, so you need the explicit `ByValue` usage to indicate you want something different.

```
public class MyStruct extends Structure {
    public class ByValue extends MyStruct implements Structure.ByValue { }
}
```

`SOMESTRUCT` is a `typedef` of `struct _SOMESTRUCT`, which is the most fundamental way of referring to that `struct`.  Both are type specifiers, and may be used interchangeably.  `_SOMESTRUCT` is often called the "tag" for the structure definition it is preceding.

Comment: So I should have added a ByValue class to the java Structure and passed it to the java mapping of the c function which should have been edited to accept a Structure.ByValue argument?
In the first example of GetSomeStruct why are there three words in the parenthesis?
Also, is there a book you can recommend that deals with JNA?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify "by value" (`struct`) semantics rather than "by reference" (`struct*`).  I'm not aware of any JNA books, however, [the project documentation](https://github.com/twall/jna) is very thorough and welcomes submissions for improvement and questions on the [jna-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/jna-users).

Comment: Not sure what I am missing. I removed "by reference" and added "by value" empty enclosed class but the function still doesnt write any data to the object created from this struct.